# Switch divs through sidemenu

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm pretty new to this and sorry for the title, I didn't know what else to call it.

I'm trying to make a little menu with 2 divs inside a div.
To the left a div with text.
To the right a div with multiple images which, when clicked, link to other pieces of text shown in the left divs.

And when the other text appears the image directing to the first piece of text goes back to the menu on the right side.

I know I'm probably not explaining it all too well. I don't know how else to explain it.

This is the html, maybe it helps

```
<div id="home">
    <div id="leftBlock">
        <img src="/images/links/image1.png" alt="image 1"width="160"/>
        #atekst#
    </div>
    <div id="rightBlock">
        <img src="/images/links/image2.png" alt="image 2" width="160"/>
        <img src="/images/links/image3.png" alt="image 3" width="160"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shew - I think we might need a little bit more to work with here... Im slightly confused!

Comment: @Mike me too. Dear user3481441 could you try to create a fiddle as jsfiddle.net with as far as you can go and then try to explain what is not working as expected? maybe also post a picture of what you want

Comment: Are you trying to link to contents in the page using one of the images on the right side. I think you can try in page html linking ref http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_locations

Comment: you need when you click on a,b or c, it will slide to right and your text content visible?

Comment: When I click on B, I need the A to go back to the right div and want the left div to show the content of B.

Comment: [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253306/sliding-multiple-elements-on-click) Possibly the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, Here is a [Work in progress fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WnC9B/203/) for you. I haven't manged to add the text functionality for you just yet, because I have other work. But I will do this ASAP.

This should set you on your way in the meantime.

```
    $('#rightBlock').on('click', '.image', function(e) {
  $('.YourPic').children('img').attr('src', $(e.target).attr('src'));
 });
```

Essentially it looks at your `righBlock` div and the images therein, and onclick it will add them to another div with a class of `"YourPic"`

**EDIT:**
Hey, so here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WnC9B/206/) which hides the image on the right. I'm not sure if this is the most effective / efficient way of doing it, but that's how I approached it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is in the direction i had in mind. Except when clicking on the A, it will show on the left, but the A must disappear from the right div.

Comment: I put a new fiddle in the answer above. Cheers, mike

Comment: You are welcome. Should I still add the text a bit later on, or are you good? :)

Comment: If that would be possible it'd be even better!

Comment: If you don't mind a few span tags and more hiding and showing, you could use this... http://jsfiddle.net/WnC9B/207/